# Определение отправляемых страницей заголовков

Tags: javascript

Как определить отправляемые страницей заголовки с помощью javascript? Подскажите функции, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "отправляемые страницей заголовки"??

Comment: К примеру, 404 еррор

Comment: Это заголовок отправляемый сервером ВМЕСТЕ со страницей

Comment: Я понимаю, что эта информация уже отправляется на страницу и выводится в тайтле и в самом контенте, но мне нужно именно "добыть" её именно средствами javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть неплохое расширение для Firefox - [livehttpheaders.mozdev.org](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)
Позволяет просматривать все заголовки, и вообще все запросы. Удобная настройка, предельно понятный интерфейс.
На JavaScript это, я считаю, нецелесообразно, да и невозможно.

[image]

Есть, правда, способ узнать средством AJAX-запроса о существовании страницы. То есть ошибка ли 404.

```
(function(link){
 var ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
   ajax.open('get', link, 1);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (ajax.readyState == 4) alert(ajax.status);
    };
  ajax.send(null);

})('/404error');
```

Такие запросы ограничены пределами доменного имени.
Где *'/404error'* - ссылка. Если её нет на сайте, выдаст 404 — номер ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко - никак. Но можно сделать что-то подобное. [Изучайте](http://www.google.ru/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=http+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8+javascript)